# PWA loses its params and query params after being added to the home screen

Tags: angularjs, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have created a PWA(Progressive Web App) using Angular6. It works perfectly as expected in the browser. My scenario is to handle all the app data based on the params I get from URL

eg: `https://<my-site.com>/app/abc123`

where `abc123` is my param which I need to add to the home screen app.

So the problem is when user adds the app to the home screen it loses all the params (I have tried using queryparams as well) and that leaves me only with the hostname. I need the whole URL to be added as the App URL. Can you please help.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: no @JRS I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 7):

When you add a web app to your homescreen, the browser will check to see if there's a [web app manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/).

If the manifest is present, the `start_url` field in the manifest will be used as the initial page when you open the web app.

If you need to customize the initial page, you'll need to change that `start_url` value in your web app manifest accordingly.

Comment: I tried that however the `start_url` doesn't allow dynamic URLs

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: This was my problem. Just removing the start_url setting from my manifest.json file caused the browser's URL to be picked up. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: `start_url` is required and if not provided the install to home screen is not possible.
Did anyone manage to solve this "dynamic" url query params?

Comment: @Royalsmed I have no issue saving to homescreen on an iPad with the start_url removed from the manifest. it still picks up the name and icon. The one weird thing is that previously it was working when I had `start_url: "."`, but I think it broke when my params got too long or started to include (url safe) symbols

Comment: Removing the `start_url` from the manifest works for me on Firefox and Chrome. However, it has the side effect that in Chrome I can only choose `Add to Homescreen` instead of `Install app`, which will result in a small browser icon being shown together with the app icon on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when my PWA manifest didn't include `start_url`.

Adding `"start_url": ""` to the manifest worked for me on iOS 16.5.

Edit: However this makes Android load the manifest file instead of the web page! I have settled on serving two different manifest files based on the `user-agent` string. One for Mobile Safari with `"start_url": ""` and one for other browsers without the `start_url` property.